# Facebook og:image ignored when og:url points to location other than current url

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to define a Facebook Open Graph Object for the URL http://www.storeyourboard.com.  Therefore, I include a Facebook meta tag for this URL in my code:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.storeyourboard.com" />
```

I would like to specify the image used for this object.  Therefore, I include a Facebook meta tag for this image in my code:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://spirecollective.com/temp/gopro/img/gopro_promo.jpg" />
```

The URL on which I am trying to create this object is located here:  http://spirecollective.com/temp/gopro/

I used the Facebook debug tool to see if the object is created successfully.  You can repeat this by visiting the Open Graph Object Debugger and debugging the url mentioned above.

As you will see, the Facebook scraper seems to be ignoring all of the meta tags on my page, and instead being redirected to the og:url location.  It's then reading the meta tags from that page instead of the ones specified on my website.

Here are all of the meta tags on my site for reference:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="I just registered to win a GoPro Hero 3 Camera!" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="StoreYourBoard.com" />
<meta property="og:description" content="StoreYourBoard.com features board racks and accessories for however you shred. Reshare this post to be entered to win a GoPro Hero 3 camera!" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.storeyourboard.com" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://spirecollective.com/temp/gopro/img/gopro_promo.jpg" />
```

Is this the intended behavior?  Why is Facebook ignoring all of my meta tags?  The open graph object documentation does not mention anything that would make me think this is expected behavior.  Am I missing something here?  Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Your og:url should be

http://spirecollective.com/temp/gopro/

and not

"http://www.storeyourboard.com"

From http://ogp.me/#metadata:

> og:url - The canonical URL of your object that will be used as its permanent ID in the graph, e.g., "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/".

Comment: My intent was to link to a webpage that is different than the page the user is sharing from.  If the a user clicks this story after it's posted to Facebook, I want them to be directed to http://www.storeyourboard.com, not http://spirecollective.com/temp/gopro/.  Is this possible?

Comment: I don't know, maybe it's possible, but I don't think it is recommended. Because the same process/trick could be used for phishing.

Comment: For example, I could post a url to facebook. thisisyourbank.com but although the image/title would be shown, the link could just send to malicioussite.com and then I could use a form to stole information about your account number, password, email, etc.

Comment: But if you want to make the user go to storeyourboard.com anyway you could put a javascript that sends the user to it after a few seconds since the arrival at spirecollective.com/temp/gopro.